# TweetSharp Send direct message with image (C#)

Tags: image, twitter, message, tweetsharp

How to send direct message with image in Twitter using TweetSharp? (C#) I didn't found how to do it.

```
SendDirectMessageOptions msgOpt = new SendDirectMessageOptions();
msgOpt.UserId = id;
msgOpt.Text = "text";
var result = service.SendDirectMessage(msgOpt);
```

Comment: I am having the exact issue, it returns null right?